# How to use dollar sign in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I use Spring MVC & jsp.

It's my homeController. return "test String";

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale,Model model){

model.addAttribute("test","test String");

return "home"; }
```

home.jsp

```
<html><head>
<% String test = ${test} %>
</head>
<body>
${test} //it shows "test String"
<%=test%>  //but it doesn't show anything. error. 
</body></html>
```

how to use dollar sign in <% %> ?

Answer (score 0):

el expression isn't allowed inside script-lets, you should be able to just use EL

Answer (score 0):

You should use either scriptlets or jstl.
It could be better to do like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<c:out value="${test}"/>
</body>
</html>
```